# Why does `undefined` extend `void` in conditional types?

Tags: typescript

Here is some code that checks if a type extends `void`. It's being run with `strict: true`.

```
type ExtendsVoid<T> = T extends void ? true : false;

type A = ExtendsVoid<number>; // false
type B = ExtendsVoid<null>; // false
type C = ExtendsVoid<void>; // true
type D = ExtendsVoid<undefined>; // true?
```

Why does `ExtendsVoid<undefined>` return true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's OK to return `undefined` from function declared as returning `void`. The actual value in javascript code at runtime will really be `undefined`.

So, for the sake of consistency, `undefined` is always assignable to `void`.

```
let z: void;
z = undefined; // ok
```

Answer (score 1):

In the expression `T extends U ? X : Y`, the keyword `extends` means "inherits from U" or "is U".

In object-oriented programming, the declaration `class Cat extends Animal` means that `Cat` is `Animal` and `Cat` has the same (or more) features as `Animal`. Another way to put it is that a cat is a more specific version of an animal. This also means that the `Cat` object can be assigned to the variable of type `Animal`.

In your example, `null` and `undefined` are more specific versions of `void`.  BTW, your `type B` is `true` as well.

In the browser console, run the function that doesn't return a value (e.g. `console.log(123);`), and it'll print `undefined`.

Comment: `B` is true only when `--strictNullChecks` is off. With strict null checks on, `null` is distinct and incompatible with either `void` or `undefined`.